# How to autoplay video on mobile web

Tags: android, autoplay

I found an article how to autoplay with tricky way.
https://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/

and I implemented the source code in my web but it doesn't work.
I don't know what I am missing.
Here is what I implemented
aspx file

```
$(document).ready(function () {var video = document.getElementById('video');video.addEventListener('click',function(){video.play();},false);

        var id = getQueryStringValue('v');
        viewvideo(id);}
```

In js file

```
varVideoid = videoid;
$("#video").empty();
var data = Ajax("../Ajax/Webmethod.aspx/getviewvideo", { videoid: videoid });
var str = '';
if (data.videourl.indexOf('youtube') == -1 && data.videourl.indexOf('youtu.be') == -1) {
    str += '<video id="video" autobuffer controls >';
    str += '<source src="' + data.videourl + '" type="video/mp4">';
    str += '<source src="' + data.videourl + '" type="video/3gpp">';
    str += '<source src="' + data.videourl + '" type="video/m4v">';
    str += '<source src="' + data.videourl + '" type="video/x-ms-wmv">';
    str += '<source src="' + data.videourl + '" type="video/webm">';
    str += '<source src="' + data.videourl + '" type="video/quicktime">';
    str += '<source src="' + data.videourl + '" type="video/ogg">';
    str += '<source src="' + data.videourl + '" type="video/mpeg">';
    str += '<source src="' + data.videourl + '" type="video/x-matroska">';
    str += '</video>';
}
```

Please help me
Thank you

Comment: Since u using jquery , why r u using document.getElementById ?

Comment: I don't have many knowlage for jquery and asp.net so please guide me thanks

Comment: Both codes u poted r js. There's no asp in your post.

Comment: ok...the first one is in aspx file that's why I said that...anyway is it possible to make it tricky autoplay?